# Combining arrays with incremental key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following structure:

```
products = array[2] {
  [0] = array[12] = stdclass[108],
  [1] = array[18] = stdclass[108],
  ....
}
```

There is one array contain two arrays, each array containing a stdclass object.
I want to combine these to arrays in order to achieve this:

```
products = array[2]{
  0 => stdclass[108],
  1 => stdclass[108],
  .....
  31 => stdclass[108]
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: have you tried `array_merge()`

Comment: I mean, show the code, that you tried, than we will help you to fix it. This is the way, that StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
for($i=0, $ic=count($products); $i<$ic; i++) {
  $products[$i] = $products[$i][0];
}
```

This obviously join only first elements of each array.

If you want it all:

```
$tmp = array();
for($i=0, $ic=count($products); $i<$ic; i++) {
  array_merge($tmp, products[$i]);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you take the first element only from $products[$i]

Comment: @VisserSander well, that was it was asked. Look at expected output in the question. Maybe I got him wrong.

Comment: True, but what he wants to achieve doesn't match the input object.
Not very clear tho

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 array_merge(products[0],products[1]);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new_array = array_merge($products[0], $products[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple take a look at the array_merge method =)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$new = array_merge($products[0], $products[1]);
```